# UIButton subclass, fill up SafeArea, inset content

Tags: ios, swift, safearealayoutguide

I'm getting the hang of using the safe area when using custom UI elements in `.xib`/`.storyboard`.

I now have the case where I have a UIButton subclass that's used everywhere throughout the app. Since it's just a subclass (and not a custom class in `.xib`) I'm not sure how I would update this to fit my needs.

See the following photo:
[image: iPhone X button]
Here the yellow is the UIButton. On 'regular' iPhones this yellow is the bottom of the screen.
What I'm trying to achieve is to have the button go all the way to the bottom of the safe area, while still being in the same position (above the safe area).

Normally I would constraint the button to `superview.bottom`, and in the button's `.xib` constraint the content (titleLabel, buttonImage, etc) to `safearea.bottom`.

Since that's not possible here, how would I do that?

I tried adding the constraints programatically in the UIButton subclass, but to not avail.

Example:

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        (titleLabel?.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor))!,
        (titleLabel?.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor))!
        ])
} else {
    // Fallback on earlier versions
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you need this cause you want bottom safe area  to be same color of the button or because you want that zone to be tappable?

Comment: Because it should be the same color. But instead of putting a view behind it with the same color, I want to achieve it by extending the button to the `superview.bottom`.

Comment: can you show the constraints of the button? you give button a height? or a topanchor?

Comment: The button has a height constraint, and is constrained with `0` to `safearea.bottom` at the moment. (In some cases it's in a `view` that has a height-constraint, don't ask me why)
But I'm open to any solution, the way it's constrained now can be changed completely if needed!

Comment: Is Save a label inside the yellow view?

Comment: No, the yellow view is the actual UIButton (or, the UIButton subclass). 'Save' is the button's title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following approach for this,

1. Create a `UIView`.
2. Add a `UILabel` to the above created `view` as a `subView`.
3. Add a `UIButton` to the above created `view` as a `subView`.

Apply proper `layout constraints` to get the desirable UI.

```
func addSaveButton() {
    let height: CGFloat = 60 + self.view.safeAreaInsets.bottom //Height based on safe area

    //Custom View
    let customView = UIView(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: self.view.bounds.height - height, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: height))
    customView.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9529411793, green: 0.6862745285, blue: 0.1333333403, alpha: 1)

    //Save Label
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "Save"
    label.textColor = UIColor.black

    //Button
    let button = UIButton(frame: customView.bounds)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onTapSaveButton), for: .touchUpInside)

    //Add label, button as subview in customView
    customView.addSubview(label)
    customView.addSubview(button)
    self.view.addSubview(customView)

    customView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    //Add constraints
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        self.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: customView.leadingAnchor),
        customView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor),
        customView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor),
        customView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: height),

        label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: customView.topAnchor, constant: 10),
        label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: customView.trailingAnchor, constant: -10),

        button.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: customView.topAnchor),
        button.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: customView.leadingAnchor),
        button.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: customView.trailingAnchor),
        button.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: customView.bottomAnchor)
        ])

}

@objc func onTapSaveButton() {
    print("Save button pressed")
}
```

**In iPhone-X**

[image]

**In iPhone-8**

[image]

**Approach 2:**

You can follow a bit more simplified approach by playing with the `button's` **`titleEdgeInsets`**.

```
func addSaveButton() {
    let height: CGFloat = 60 + self.view.safeAreaInsets.bottom

    //Button
    let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.height - height, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: height))
    button.setTitle("Save", for: .normal)
    button.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9529411793, green: 0.6862745285, blue: 0.1333333403, alpha: 1)
    button.contentHorizontalAlignment = .right
    button.contentVerticalAlignment = .top
    button.titleEdgeInsets.top = 10
    button.titleEdgeInsets.right = 10
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onTapSaveButton), for: .touchUpInside)

    self.view.addSubview(button)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    //Add constraints
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        self.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: button.leadingAnchor),
        button.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor),
        button.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor),
        button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: height)
        ])
}
```

You can do the same thing in `storyboard/subclassing` easily. I think this one is better than the previous one.

**Approach 3:**

Subclass `UIButton` and use it to create your button programatically.

```
class CustomButton: UIButton {
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        self.contentHorizontalAlignment = .right
        self.contentVerticalAlignment = .top
        self.titleEdgeInsets.top = 10
        self.titleEdgeInsets.right = 10
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this helps me a lot. Just wondering: is this possible without having to create a UIView, but just using a UIButton subclas?

Comment: I tried the 2nd approach but didn't get it working exactly how I want it. This has probably to do with our current implementation. The 3rd approach I didn't try yet, but I hope it will work since it seems to be the cleanest. Just wondering: is `draw()` the right place, since this is called many times. Correct?
Also, would this (3rd approach) make the button size itself automatically in height, depending on the font size?